# Example of non-unique extension of measure for the pre-integral in the Stone-Daniell Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, vector-lattices

**Prerequisites**

**Definition 1** Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a non-empty collection of real-valued functions on a set $X$. Then $\mathcal{L}$ is a *real vector space* iff for all $f,g\in\mathcal{L}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R},cf+g\in\mathcal{L}$. Let $f\lor g:=\mathrm{max}(f,g),f\land g:=\mathrm{min}(f,g)$. A vector space $\mathcal{L}$ of functions is called a *vector lattice* iff for all $f$ and $g$ in $\mathcal{L}$, $f\lor g\in\mathcal{L}$. Then also $f\land g\equiv-(-f\lor-g)\in\mathcal{L}$. The vector lattice $\mathcal{L}$ will be called a *Stone* vector lattice iff for all $f\in\mathcal{L}, f\land1\in\mathcal{L}$.

**Definition 2** Given a set $X$ and a vector lattice $\mathcal{L}$ of real functions on $X$, a *pre-integral* is a function $I$ from $\mathcal{L}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ such that:

(a) $I$ is linear: $I(cf+g)=cI(f)+I(g)$ for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f,g\in\mathcal{L}$.

(b) $I$ is nonegative, in the sense that whenever $f\in\mathcal{L}$ and $f\geq0$ (everywhere on $X$), then $I(f)\geq0$.

(c) $I(f_n)\downarrow0$ whenever $f_n\in\mathcal{L}$ and $f_n(x)\downarrow0$ for all $x$.

**Definition 3** For the rest of this post, assume given a set $X$, a vector lattice $\mathcal{L}$ of real functions on $X$, and a pre-integral $I$ on $\mathcal{L}$. For any two functions $f$ and $g$ in $\mathcal{L}$ with $f\leq g$ (that is $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x$), let
\begin{equation}
[f,g):=\{\langle x,t\rangle\in X\times\mathbb{R}:f(x)\leq t<g(x)\}.
\end{equation}
Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the collection of all $[f,g)$ for $f\leq g$ in $\mathcal{L}$. Define $\nu$ on $\mathcal{S}$ by $\nu([f,g)):=I(g-f)$. So if $g\geq0$, then $I(g)=\nu([0,g))$, and for any $f\in\mathcal{L},I(f)=\nu([0,f^+))-\nu([0,f^-))$.

**Theorem (A. C. Zaanen)** $\nu$ extends to a countably additive measure on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{T}$ generated by $\mathcal{S}$.

**Theorem (Stone-Daniell)** Let $I$ be a pre-integral on a Stone vector lattice $\mathcal{L}$. Then there is a measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that $I(f)=\int fd\mu$ for all $f\in\mathcal{L}$. The measure $\mu$ is uniquely determined on the smallest $\sigma$-ring $\mathcal{B}$ for which all functions in $\mathcal{L}$ are measurable.

*Proof* Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the collection of all sets $f^{-1}((1,\infty))$ for $f\in\mathcal{L}$. Then $\mathcal{M}$ contains, for any $f\in\mathcal{L}$ and $r>0$, the sets $f^{-1}((r,\infty))=(f/r)^{-1}((1,\infty))$ and $f^{-1}((-\infty,-r))=(-f)^{-1}((r,\infty))$. Since the intervals $(-\infty,-r)$ and $(r,\infty)$ for $r>0$ generate the $\sigma$-ring of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ not containing 0, $\mathcal{M}$ generates the $\sigma$-ring $\mathcal{B}$ defined in the statement of the theorem.

...

**Problem**

Give an example where the measure $\mu$ in the Stone-Daniell theorem has more than one extension to the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ for which all functions in $\mathcal{L}$ are measurable, and where $\mu$ is bounded on the smallest $\sigma$-ring $\mathcal{R}$ for which the functions are measurable.

**My efforts**:

We will make use of the following lemma.

**Lemma** Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a $\sigma$-ring of subsets of a set $X$. Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{R}$.

(1) $\mathcal{S}$ consists of all sets in $\mathcal{R}$ and all complements of sets in $\mathcal{R}$.

(2) Let $\mu$ be countably additive from $\mathcal{R}$ into $[0,\infty]$. For any set $C\subset X$ let $\mu_*(C):=\mathrm{sup}\{\mu(B):B\subset C,B\in\mathcal{R}\}$ (inner measure). Then $\mu_*$ restrict to $\mathcal{S}$ is a measure, which equals $\mu$ on $\mathcal{R}$.

(3) The extension of $\mu$ to a measure on $\mathcal{S}$ is unique if and only if either $\mathcal{S}=\mathcal{R}$ or $\mu_*(X\setminus A)=+\infty$ for all $A\in\mathcal{R}$.

By the lemma, the example must satisfy $\mathcal{A}\neq\mathcal{B}$ and $\mu_*(X\setminus B)<+\infty$ for some $B\in\mathcal{B}$. We can firstly find such a $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mu$, and then construct a Stone lattice and pre-integral.

First I tried $X=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{B}$ consisting of all Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}\setminus(-1,1)$, and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure. $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-ring. $\mathcal{A}$ consists of all Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$, so $\mathcal{A}\neq\mathcal{B}$. Pick $B=\mathbb{R}\setminus(-1,1)\setminus(2,3)$. Then $\mu_*(X\setminus B) =\mu_*((-1,1)\cup(2,3)) =\mu((2,3))=1<+\infty$. So this $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mu$ work. Next we need to construct the Stone lattice and pre-integral. We need to find a Stone vector lattice $\mathcal{L}$ of $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathcal{B}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-ring for which all functions in $\mathcal{L}$ are measurable. This seems impossible if we look at the proof of the Stone-Daniell Theorem. We can let one $f^{-1}((1,\infty))$ lie outside $(-1,1)$. But another one must be inside with appropriate $r$ by $(f/r)^{-1}((1,\infty))$.

Any easy example of a $\sigma$-ring which is not a $\sigma$-algebra would be the collection of all countable subsets of an uncountable set. So I tried   $X=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{B}$ being the collection of all countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure. But $\mu_*(X\setminus B)=+\infty$ for all $B\in\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: This is similar to the Caratheodory extension theorem (in fact equivalent). Any measure $mu$ of the countable additive measure on a ring $R$ has an extension $\bar{\mu}$ defined a a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{L}$ containing the ring $R$ such that $(X,\mathcal{L},\bar{\mu})$ is complete. Any pother extension $\nu$ of $\mu$ to some sigma-algebra containing $R$ satisfies $\mu=\nu$ on $\sigma(R)$. (See Kallenber, foundations of probability).

Comment: @OliverDiaz One of the difficulties for me to construct the example is unable to understand measurable in sigma rings. The only criterion satisfied by sigma algebra but not satisfied by sigma ring is that sigma ring does not have the whole $X$. The biggest set in sigma ring must be subset of $X$. The sigma ring must have a hollow.  But the function is defined on $X$. That hollow part has corresponding image in $\mathbb{R}$. The inverse image of this cannot be in the sigma ring. For example, the sigma ring is all Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}∖(−1,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{L}=\{f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R : f \text{ is continuous and } \textrm{supp} f \subseteq [0,1]\}$.
(In other words, $f \in \mathcal{L}$ if and only if $f$ is defined on $X=\Bbb R$, $f$ is continuous and $f$ is zero outside $[0,1]$).

It is easy to see that $\mathcal{L}$ is a Stone vector lattice.  Let us define the function $I$ from $\mathcal{L}$ into $\Bbb R$ by $I(f) = \int f \, d\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. It is easy to see that $I$ is a pre-integral.

Now, let $\mathcal{B}$ be the smallest $\sigma$-ring for which all functions in $\mathcal{L}$ are measurable. It is not difficult to prove that $\mathcal{B}= \{ B \subseteq \Bbb R: B \text{ is a Borel subset of } [0,1]\}$. There is an unique measure $\mu$ defined on $\mathcal{B}$, such that $I(f) = \int f \, d\mu$. Namely, $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on the Borel subsets of $[0,1]$.

Now let $\mathcal{A}$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra  for which all functions in $\mathcal{L}$ are measurable. It is not difficult to prove that $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{B} \cup \{B \cup (\Bbb R \setminus [0,1]): B \in \mathcal{B}\} $.

Note that, for all $c \in \Bbb R$, the set function defined on $\mathcal{A}$ by
$\mu_c(B) = \mu(B)$ and $\mu_c(B \cup (\Bbb R \setminus [0,1])) = \mu(B)+c$,  for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$, is a measure and it is an extension of $\mu$ to $\mathcal{A}$. Moreover, for all $c \in \Bbb R$,   $I(f) = \int f \, d\mu_c$. So we see that the extension of $\mu$ to $\mathcal{A}$ is not uniquely determined.

Comment: Here functions are defined on $X=[0,1]$. $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra for $[0,1]$. I agree that $\mathcal{B}$ is only a $\sigma$-ring for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra for $\mathbb{R}$. But the spirit of the Stone-Daniell Theorem is about ring and algebra on $X$, which is $[0,1]$ in this case. Shouldn't we find $\sigma$-algebra for $[0,1]$?

Comment: @JunkWarrior , No.  Please read carefully the first line. The functions are defined on $X=\Bbb R$.

Comment: Then what does supp $f\subset[0,1]$ mean? Do you mean $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ but is zero outside $[0,1]$?

Comment: @JunkWarrior. Exactly.

Comment: @JunkWarrior The situation is similar to what happens in your example.  In my example, the functions are defined on $X = \Bbb R$ but they are zero outside $[0,1]$. In your example, the functions are defined on $X=(-1,1)$ but they are zero outside $(0,1)$.

Comment: @JunkWarrior Please, let me know if you have any other question regarding my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A $\sigma$-ring is a collection $\mathcal{R}$ of sets, with $\emptyset\in\mathcal{R}$, such that $A\setminus B\in\mathcal{R}$ for any $A\in\mathcal{R}$ and $B\in\mathcal{R}$ , and such that $\bigcup_{j\geq1}A_j\in\mathcal{R}$ whenever $A_j\in\mathcal{R}$ for $j=1,2,\ldots$. So any $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-ring. Conversely, a $\sigma$-ring $\mathcal{R}$ of subsets of a set $X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$ if and only if $X\in\mathcal{R}$. For example, the set of all countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\sigma$-ring which is not a $\sigma$-algebra. If $f$ is a real-valued function on a set $X$, and $\mathcal{R}$ is a $\sigma$-ring of subsets of $X$, then $f$ is said to be *measurable* for $\mathcal{R}$ iff $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{R}$ for any Borel set $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ not containing 0. (If this is true for general Borel sets, then $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=X\in\mathcal{R}$ implies $\mathcal{R}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra).

For any $c\in\mathbb{R}$, define the function $f_c$ on $X=(-1,1)$ by
\begin{equation}
f_c = \begin{cases}
c, & x>0 \\
0, & x\leq0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Define $\mathcal{L}:=\{f_c|c\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Obviously $\mathcal{L}$ is a Stone vector lattice.
\begin{equation}
f_c^{-1}((1,\infty)) = \begin{cases}
\emptyset, & c\leq1 \\
(0,1), & c>1.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f_c^{-1}((-\infty,-1)) = \begin{cases}
\emptyset, & c\geq-1 \\
(0,1), & c<-1.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Thus the smallest $\sigma$-ring for which each $f_c$ is measurable is $\mathcal{B}=\{\emptyset,(0,1)\}$.
\begin{equation}
I(f_c)=\int^1_{-1}f_cd\mu=\int^1_0f_cd\mu=c\int^1_0d\mu=c\mu((0,1)).
\end{equation}
Thus $\mu$ is determined by $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu((0,1))=I(f_1)$.

The smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{B}$ is $\mathcal{A}=\{\emptyset,(0,1),(-1,1),(-1,0]\}$. The extension $\bar{\mu}$ of $\mu$ to \$\mathcal{A}$ is nonunique. The following are two examples.

(1) $\bar{\mu}((-1,0])=1,\bar{\mu}((-1,1))=1+I(f_1)$.

(2) $\bar{\mu}((-1,0])=2,\bar{\mu}((-1,1))=2+I(f_1)$.